# Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a case statement and am getting the subject line error message.

```
SELECT  
     IndexValue = CONVERT(VARCHAR,
                     CASE WHEN _608 in ('value1', 'value2')
                               THEN _688/100
                               ELSE ''
                     END)
FROM DB1
```

- Field _608 datetype = varchar(26)
- Field _688 datatype = decimal(23,10)

I've also looked at the other questions/answers and could not find anything that answers this simple question.

Comment: So what values have got that don't work?

Comment: This is just painful. Why store number in varchar columns? You are mixing datatypes all over the place here which is causing performance problems you can't see.

Comment: The real issue is because you have a case expression with mixed datatypes in it. When the value meets your criteria you are doing math but otherwise you are trying to use an empty string which can't be cast as numeric.

Comment: Sean, Your feedback and solution is appreciated and worked like a charm. We've converted from MySQL to SQL Server and although they are similar, some functions are a  bit challenging. Good to know about the length (I saw "optional" and thus left it off). I wasn't sure how to get the datatypes from differing to same and column names were just made up in the hopes of not making it confusing for others at the same level as myself. _688 is an integer, so i knew I was good to go with that. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many things wrong with your query it is hard to pinpoint them all.

You convert to varchar but don't specify the length. The default varies by context and as such you should always specify the length. You are mixing datatypes inside a single column. Your column names are just plain awful. You are doing division by a hard coded integer and unless _688 is a numeric you are going to get integer division which is probably not what you want.

Try something along these lines.

```
SELECT IndexValue = isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CASE WHEN [_608] in ('value1', 'value2') THEN [_688]/100.0 END), '') 
FROM DB1
```

Comment: This is exactly what you'd want for the query you provided, but without another column to provide a context to your IndexValue it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sean Lange, Your feedback is greatly appreciated! We've converted from MySQL to SQL Server and although they are similar, some functions are a  bit challenging.